# How to reference `baseUrl` in the `<style>` section of a vue.js SFC?

Tags: vuejs2

How may we reference `baseUrl` in the `<style>` section of a vue.js SFC?

```
/src/views/Home.vue
<style scoped>
@import url(<%= BASE_URL %>static/required_styles.css); // does not work
</style>
```

Directory structure:

```
|--public
|  --static
|     --required_styles.css
|--src
|  --views
|    --Home.vue
```

It's not clear how to do this from the docs on static asset handling:

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public folder is for files that you want to be served directly on the server without going through webpack. An example would be minified css who's styles you use. In that case you would just add the css path to `vue.config.js` or the header of `index.html`. If you are importing in the styles tag the css will be pull through your build process (e.g. webpack) when the component is compiled. This means you should not put the .css file in the `public` folder, and should use a relative path for the import.